# Testing webapp for Websphere 7

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-7, java-ee-5

I am wondering what is the best way of testing webapp deployed on Websphere 7. If I consider, that Websphere 7 has no embedded container like for example Glassfish, I don't know, how should I effectively test the app. I mean especially cases, when I need to test data access layer with hibernate, which I usually have on separate EJB.
In other cases I use basic JUnit tests and if I need to set some attributes (like other EJB), I use reflection, but configuring EJB bean to be able to use Hibernate throw reflection seems to be difficult.
Has anybody some experience or could recommend some tools? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option might be in-container testing, perhaps using something like [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).

If you would rather have self-contained unit tests, your best option is probably public methods for resource injection (e.g., `@Resource public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em)`) rather than private fields, which would require reflection as you say.